# Simplicial homotopy groups - reference request

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am looking for a reference for the definition 2.6 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+homotopy+group, which states 
"The simplicial homotopy groups of any simplicial set, not necessarily Kan, are those of any of its Kan fibrant replacements",
as I can't find it anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the first deinition of that knd was given by Kan in his paper [A combinatorial definition of homotopy groups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970006?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). It is given using the $Ex^\infty$ functor in section 4 (which is curiously numbered as 5). It is pretty standard to see that any other fibrant replacement has the same homotopy groups.